# Timed out after 120 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id - error in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i am getting Timed out after 120 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: draggable error message. i am trying to drag and drop.
the link to the page is - http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/droppable.php
please help.

web page is :

```
    <style id="firepath-matching-node-style" type="text/css">.firepath-    matching-node { outline: 2px dashed #00F;}</style>
</head>
<body style="cursor: auto;">
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content ui-draggable ui-draggable-    handle" style="position: relative; width: 100px; right: auto; height: 100px; bottom: auto; left: 9px; top: -3px;">
<p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header ui-droppable">
</body>
Code :

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);// 1 minute 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/figure")));
    WebElement droppable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper'/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a/figure"));
    droppable.click();
    WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);// 1 minute 
    wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("draggable")));
    WebElement drag = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
    WebElement drop = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='droppable']"));
    (new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(drag,drop).perform();
```

Comment: http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/droppable.php

on clicking on the link they will ask to register. we can give any junk value and register. click on droppable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the website , the drag and drop elements are located inside an  iframe. You need to switch your webdriver to the iframe and then you can do the drag and drop.

Try doing it like this before dealing the drag and drop:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```